# C# Ticks to Time - wrong conversion

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to convert ticks into a formatted date/time value but I noticed that the times are not correct.

In below example, the value of numberOfTicks1 is smaller than numberOfTicks2. However, when I create a formatted date/time value of it, numberOfTicks2 is about 50s less than numberOfTicks1...

Why is this happening? Should I convert them in a different way?

```
long numberOfTicks1 = 635904556104808905;
long numberOfTicks2 = 635904559203480591;

DateTime myDate1 = new DateTime(numberOfTicks1);
DateTime myDate2 = new DateTime(numberOfTicks2);

Console.WriteLine(myDate1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:ss.fff"));
Console.WriteLine(myDate2.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:MM:ss.fff"));

// Result
//07-02-2016 15:02:50.480
//07-02-2016 15:02:00.348
```

** UPDATE **

```
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
```

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Comment: Just noticed the mistake... it should be HH:mm:ss and not HH:MM:ss

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I *strongly* suspect that's because you are using [`MM` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#MM_Specifier) instead [`mm` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#mmSpecifier) for minutes.

```
Console.WriteLine(myDate1.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
Console.WriteLine(myDate2.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff"));
```

Real result should be:

```
07-02-2016 15:26:50.480
07-02-2016 15:32:00.348
```

Comment: Yes you are right. Just noticed it. Thanks.